# windows soap not found in symfony2 cron

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I was make a symfony2 cron on linux OS , and want install my solution on windows , but on windows don't found soapClient in cron , but if go to url and use soapClient there work , i don't have any ideea why in cron don't work and to url found soapClient libery , If soameone know please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was beacuse windows have 2 php.ini , 1 is for apache ( that was work in browser beacuse apache was enable dll soap ) , and 1 is for command line , cron use comand line then need was enable dll for command line php.ini